ZFS disk replacement identification?
I am still a newbie with ZFS. We had a faulty disk in a ZFS pool (using Ubuntu 22.04.2. LTS). It had been replaced automatically by a spare disk (I try to quote only the relevant parts):
zpool status ZFS
pool: ZFS
state: DEGRADED
...
              raidz1-2                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48513d8d    ONLINE       0     0     0
                spare-1                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
                  wwn-0x5000039c48512f59  UNAVAIL      4   128     0
                  wwn-0x5000039c48508ee1  ONLINE       0     0     0
...
            spares
              wwn-0x5000039c48508ee1      INUSE     currently in use
    

errors: No known data errors

I detached the faulty spare, after which the physical disk was replaced:
zpool detach ZFS wwn-0x5000039c48512f59

Now it seems ok:
zpool status ZFS
  pool: ZFS
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 826G in 01:40:08 with 0 errors on Thu May  2 00:18:18 2024
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        ZFS                         ONLINE       0     0     0
...
              raidz1-2                  ONLINE       0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48513d8d  ONLINE       0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48508ee1  ONLINE       0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48513d35  ONLINE       0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48510189  ONLINE       0     0     0
                wwn-0x5000039c48516f0d  ONLINE       0     0     0
            logs
              wwn-0x5002538022c12e30    ONLINE       0     0     0
            cache
              wwn-0x5002538022c12d70    ONLINE       0     0     0
    

errors: No known data errors

The remaining task is to add the new disk as a spare, but how do I identify which is the right disk to add with:
zpool add -f ZFS spare (disk)
lsblk

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdj                         8:144  0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sdj1                      8:145  0   7.3T  0 part
└─sdj9                      8:153  0     8M  0 part
sdk                         8:160  0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sdk1                      8:161  0   7.3T  0 part
└─sdk9                      8:169  0     8M  0 part
sdl                         8:176  0   7.3T  0 disk
sdm                         8:192  0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sdm1                      8:193  0   7.3T  0 part
└─sdm9                      8:201  0     8M  0 part
...

ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/|grep sdl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 May 13 12:46 scsi-35000c500f8025907 -> ../../sdl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 May 13 12:46 scsi-SSEAGATE_ST8000NM024B_WWZ51SS9 -> ../../sdl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 May 13 12:46 wwn-0x5000c500f8025907 -> ../../sdl

Am I correct in reasoning that because sdl is the only disk that isn't partitioned or connected to any LVM etc., it must be the new replacement disk, which I should add as a spare:
zpool add -f ZFS spare wwn-0x5000c500f8025907

Or should I try to double-check this somehow, like checking that sdl really does not contain any data or is in use (how?), can it been seen in syslog or blkid that this disk was recently added, etc.?
Naturally I should have checked those things, like to which disk the unavailable wwn was pointing to etc. before the disk swap, but I keep learning these things as I do...

You're probably looking for zpool status -L, try it.

Thanks, I guess that, and lsblk showing sdl not seemingly being attached/used for anything, gave me enough confidence to add it as a spare. Seems to be ok now.
